# How to do computation in one thread and save result in another thread in matlab

Tags: multithreading, matlab

I should read data from a sensor (LiDAR) and save it frame by frame in MATLAB. The problem is that when I save each frame, it takes a lot of time (due to the big size of it) and this problem decreases the frame per second significantly. As a result, I am searching for a multithreading approach to saving each frame in a different thread, so the saving process does not affect the final frame per second. My code structure is as follows:

```
while (has_next_frame) 
   frame, has_next_frame = getNextFrame();
   save(frame); % I want to do this line in parallel
end
```

I tried to use Matlab's **parallel computing toolbox**, but `parfor` is not helpful here as I do not have separate tasks to do all of them in parallel. I just do not want to complete the saving process and then get the next frame!

Comment: You are not understanding what parallel computing is. You don't want to do something "in parallel " i.e. at the same time. You want your `getNextFrame()` to keep runing and to save "in the background". It makes no logical sense that you in paralel read a variable and save it, because if both processes start at the same time, how does the saving process get the variable? Its an inherently serial thing. you are barking at the wrong tree here.

Comment: So, do you say there is no way to do so? As there is a software that does it and gets frame per second = 10, but with the saving process, I get fps~=3. Is there anyway to save each frame in background and continue the whole loop?

Comment: you can always store it in RAM, and then save it in the end, but you can not run it forever, of course. Even if you could do it in parallel, if you run at 10 fps for 10h then the queue of bakcground processes for saving will be huge and all your data will be in RAM anyway.

Comment: what about having different codes to save for example every 100 frames, so we can have queue management that can save each 100 frames in parallel and delete them from ram, is it ok?

Comment: If your saving takes more time than your adquiring, there is no way you can parallelize it, you see that? The bottleneck will always be saving.